# Understanding cost-complexity pruning in regression trees

Tags: regression, cart

I am trying to understand how an optimal tree length is determined using cost-complexity pruning.

Visit this lecture note screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgr742zg45ahqgr/Screenshot%202015-02-04%2018.17.03.png?dl=0

In the highlighted equation, I don't understand how C(T) or alpha is calculated. My thought process is that a large tree is grown and then a subtree is created and then they are compared but I don't understand how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What don't you understand about how to calculate C(T)? Given a value for \alpha, you highlighted the equation.

Comment: I don't understand then how values of alpha are calculated or selected?

Comment: Take a look at this [scikit-learn tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html). It might enlighten you.